# Geocoder getAddressLine(0) works, but not getLocality()?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-geocoder

I'm trying to get users city by location, but I can't get ONLY the City!

I tried pretty much everything I believe but nothing seem to work, or, actually, the only thing working for getting user-info by location is "getAddressLine(0)".

Below is code

```
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());

        String city="unknown";

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude(), 1);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.d(TAG, "getAddress failed: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Couldn't find city!";
        }

        if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {

            city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // Returns full address!

            // city = addresses.get(0).getLocality(); // Returns only an empty string " ".
        }

        return city;
```

So, I wonder how I could get only CITY and not full address. Also, WHY is "getLocality()" returning an useless empty string?

I'm still wonder why is getLocality() don't work,

but I created a temporarily solution as below code:

```
if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {

        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);   // StreetAddress -> StreetAddress Number -> Postal Code -> City -> Country
        String[] splitAddress = address.split(" ");     // Splits address where there is a space, creating array with 5 index. Index 4 should be CITY!

        city=splitAddress[4].substring(0,splitAddress[4].length()-1);   // Saves city into city-string, and removes a comma from the getAddressLine(0)!

        Log.d("SplittedAddress", Arrays.toString(splitAddress));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the city, try:

```
String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
```

Comment: Ok if it works I mark this as correct answer. Do you have a link for full documentation?

Comment: It depends on the lat/lon that you start with.  There are large parts of cities, such as corporate parks, that are not geocoded.  Therefore, a lot of that address information might be empty.  So, you have to code for the best.  The link that I go back to, to remind me of what is what is this Question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096011/what-does-each-androids-location-address-method-return

Comment: Ok but why is addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) find the city but not getLocality() or getAddressLine(1)? Thanks for link!

Comment: Like I said, it is somewhat random.  For most well geocoded US addresses, you can and should use getLocality().  However, I think the methods such as getLocality() are newer, so, if addresses were geocoded before the Locality field was available, it was never populated.  However, then, it might be available in getAddressLine(1) (along with the State and Zip).  I typically use logic such as, if getLocality is blank, then getAddressLine(1) and substring the first text before the comma (,) for city.  If that is blank, just deal with a blank city.

Comment: Michael Dougan I edited my post, what do you think about that solution?

Comment: That's a pretty good solution.  However, you have to account for different types of qualified addresses such as 333 North Main Street Ventura CA 93001 (index 4), or 333 Main Street Ventura CA (index 3), or 333 North Lake View Terrace Ventura CA 93001 (index 5), or 333 North Lake View Terrace West Hollywood CA 91801 (index 5 and 6).  So, it's hard to find a solution that takes everything into account.

Comment: Ok great! Thank you very much for the advice! I hope, for this project, it will work great! I'm only developing for a specific country and the address-array should look the same for all positions. So, if user is based in another country, it won't make a big deal, since we won't target those users. Hopefully the getLocality() will be improved in the future!

Answer (score 0):

```
Adress.get(1).getAddressLine(0);
```